# How do I use JavaScriptSerializer in ASP.NET 5 RC 1?

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, javascriptserializer

In earlier versions of ASP.NET, `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` was available.
usage:

```
Dictionary<string, object> sample = (Dictionary<string, object>)new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject("...");
```

In ASP.NET 5 RC 1, `JavaScriptSerializer` does not seem to be available, by default.

1. How do I add `JavaScriptSerializer` in ASP.NET 5 RC 1?
2. Since `System.Web` is not available in the new version, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to serialize/deserialize json.